# Manipulating a group view in a ExpandableListView from the child view

Tags: android

I'm building an `ExpandableListView` in which there are groups of radio buttons.

Currently, I am able to handle the click event on each radio button and select the corresponding one and deselect the others. But there is just one more thing needed to make it perfect. That is displaying the value of the selected checkbox in the group view so the user can see what is selected without expanding it.

For that purpose, I have a `TextView` in the group view. Is it possible to update that `TextView` when a checkbox is selected in the child view?

Here is a screenshot of what I have right now:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Basically what I want to accomplish is to make it write the value of the selected checkbox instead of "Regular".

Thanks.

Comment: *Is it possible to update that TextView when a checkbox is selected in the child view?* - yes. When that event occurs then update the data of the group view and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example, it seems perfectly reasonable to save a reference to your `TextView` inside a member variable when it is created. you can then easily update its value by calling `setText()` on it from within your checkbox's click handler.

it is neither necessary nor desirable to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: And what will happen when the widget will recycle the group views as the user scrolls them in and outside of the screen?

Comment: i rather doubt the questioner is recycling this group view. if she is, she can easily add a line to her `getView()` function that compares the recycled view to the member variable and sets the member variable to null if they match.

Comment: @j__m I do recycle the views. I had completely forgot the approach I could take with `notifyDataSetChanged` which will eliminate all the need to save instances of the views and will keep me from playing magic. I would store the selected/unselected states in a variable and I can easily call `notifyDataSetChanged` to redraw. 

P.S. I thought in programming/computer based sites we would normally assume OP is of male gender. You amazed me with your guess, but there is a picture for the sake of all that is Holy. I'm a he! ;)

Comment: obviously a single member variable wouldn't do the trick if you have a large collection of data - i was going off the picture - but regardless, `nofifyDataSetChanged` will rebuild the entire ui, and is thus a bit wasteful for the purpose. there's nothing magic about using `getView()` to detect recycling - all recycled views have to come through that function - but there's multiple approaches to every problem. and yes, i realize most people assume male by default; i do the opposite intentionally. = )