# Update ChildView of a groupView in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an `ExpandableListView` contains a lot of groupViews each one of them contains a lot of childViews, now I want to access these childViews in case of an action in a view in their groupView.

What I did is the following, using the listView itself, I'm handling `onGroupCollapse()` event:

So, in the adapter, I'm handling the `getGroupView()` method to handle this group childViews changes:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    .
    .
    .
    // the view to alter the childViews accordingely
    CheckBox mCheckBox= convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.mCheckBox);

    // the action on that view
    mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // get the childViews count
            int n = getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
            // loop through them
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                // get each chilView separetely
                View childView = getChildView(groupPosition, i, i == n - 1, null, parent);
                // get the required view in the childView to be changed
                TextView sectionName = childView.findViewById(R.id.section);
                // make the required change
                sectionName.setText("some text");
            }
        }
    });
    .
    .
    .
    return convertView;
}
```

What I'm getting is nothing to be changed regarding these textViews text, and what I got while debugging is that the childView is being retrieved successfully and the textView also, so there is no errors at all happening while getting the chilldView or its views, the only thing is that the view of the childView is not responding to any change.

Comment: add notifyDataSetChanged() in for loop or in setOnCheckedChangeListener method and check if its working or not

Comment: already tried that and didn't work, it does make sense as I'm not changing the data set included

Comment: are you trying to do somthing like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584131/manipulating-a-group-view-in-a-expandablelistview-from-the-child-view

Comment: not quite but same concept, except I can't do that because I'm here handling a lot of child views and I can't hold all of them in member variables.

Comment: I came across a same example to refresh exapandable listview but here view holeder is used it might be helpful to take one look in it  http://www.kylemallette.com/android/2013/09/16/refreshing-lists-part2.html

Comment: one question was there are you using your own custom exapandable listview or any other library like this https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/